# using c++ wss server with websocket++ or other c++ websocket lib

Tags: c++, websocket

I am trying to write a c++ websocket server and have browser/chrome clients connect over websockets, for a multiplayer game. The websocket c++ library I'm using atm is websocketpp or websocket++. I wrote an app that allows clients to connect over ws and localhost, but when I add an ip for the address, connections don't occur at all. Now I think I have to use ssl and wss for ip connection? I tried it and there is some connection activity, but then the handshake times out. Could I be experiencing cross-orgin issues, or what, do i need ssl? I am new to websockets. Could the problem be my ssl certs I made with openssl? I can post code, or if you are familiar with a c++ library to do websockets, what is it? Is this even a possible thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons why it won't connect over ip.

The first is port forwarding. On a local network it's not necessary but running a server over a remote network, portforwarding has to be done. You can just run your server then use a simple port checker (there's many websites for them) to see if a connection can be established.

The other reason could be as you said ssl. If you are running your client on a web host, the host may require a connection to be made over ssl/wss for websockets. If your server isn't running a valid ssl certificate then this could prevent the client from connecting to your server. I know for exampe Github pages requires the server to be running wss or valid ssl certificates on the server side in order for a client connection to be established; however, if you use a custom domain name for Github pages then you can disable the need for ssl.

In order to get valid ssl certificates you would need to register a domain for your ip address then either buy certificates or use free certificates from zerossl or other distributors.

Here is a [game](https://reverseflags.me) I have written which connects to a c++ server which I'm running on my own machine with its own domain with valid ssl certificates and the client is running on github pages with a custom domain I have registered.

It's basically multiplayer minesweeper where the objective is to locate the flags rather than avoid them.